# Is Buttigieg old enough to be eligible to become the president?

Tags: united-states, election, president

According to the Wiki page [Pete Buttigieg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Buttigieg) was born on January 19, 1982.

On January 20, 2021, the president sworn in date, he will be 39 years old.

If he wins the president election, will he be able to swear in as the president of U.S.A?

Comment: he was old enough in 2017 -- by a day.

Comment: Why didn't you look up the presidential age of candidacy before asking this question?

Comment: @user76284 I live in Taiwan (Republic of China, please do not confuse it with People's Republic of China). The age limit of the presidency is 40 there, please see [this page](https://law.moj.gov.tw/ENG/LawClass/LawAll.aspx?pcode=A0000001). For some reason, I confused the Taiwan presidency age limit with the US limit. That's why I had this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [age requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_eligibility_legislation#Presidential_eligibility) for US presidents is 35; see [Article II, Section 1, Clause 5 of the Constitution](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/articleii):

> No person except a natural born citizen, or a citizen of the United States, at the time of the adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the office of President; neither shall any person be eligible to that office who shall not have attained to the age of thirty five years, and been fourteen Years a resident within the United States.

As Buttigieg will be 39, and there are no questions about his residency or citizenship status, he would be able to swear in as president.